# 'ddlPrefix' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown for prefix, the value for dropdown from a table. The values are listed below
    --Select--
    Dr.
    Mr.
    Mrs.
    Ms.
    Miss.
    Other..
When the user select the value -1,then a text box should appear,otherwise hide that.

```
<tr>
    <td class="leftTD">
        <span class="textfield">Prefix</span> <span class="required">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="rightTD">
        <div class="highlight">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrefix" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" TabIndex="12"
                onchange="chekRequiredField(this); javascript:hideRow(this.id,'trOther');">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="trOther" runat="server" style="display: none;">
    <td class="leftTD">
        <span class="textfield">Other Title</span>
    </td>
    <td class="rightTD">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" TabIndex="12" MaxLength="50" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Code Behind Code, The method for getting dropdown value given below:

```
private void PopulateDetails(int registrationid)
{
    ddlTitle.SelectedValue = BLUtil.ToString(objMOAdministrativeApproval.ObjAdministrativeApproval.Tittle);
    if (ddlPrefix.SelectedValue == "-1")
    {
        trOther.Style.Add("display", "");
        txtOther.Text = BLUtil.HtmlDecode(objMOAdministrativeApproval.ObjAdministrativeApproval.OtherTitle);
    }
    else
    {
        trOther.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
}
```

Sometimes, I will get an error in PopulateDetails method. But sometimes its ok.

```
Method Name : PopulateDetails(int registrationid)
Message : 'ddlPrefix' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
```

How can I handle this exception?

Comment: What is that sometimes condition? I am sure that *sometimes* condition is consistent. Meaning there is a condition which fails always. I see a problem with `ddlTitle.SelectedValue = BLUtil.ToString(objMOAdministrativeApproval.ObjAdministrativeApproval.Tittle);`. Such dropdownlist error occurs when try to set a selected value to the item which was not present in the collection that you bound dropdownlist with, initially.

Comment: I check the database table values and it is contained in the above list.I don't know in which scenario the error occur

Comment: @Monica - Your method says `PopulateDetails` but where are you actually binding your dropdown? The error message is definitely because the value which you are passing does not exist in the dropdown.

Comment: When checking your database to make sure the value is in the list, check that there is no white-space and that the case is identical. Been burned by the case-sensitivity myself once upon a time. Also check for null values.